# Search a word in a string using php function

Tags: php, string, function

When i search for "bank", it should display Bank-List1, Bank-List2 from the following list.

Railway-List, Bank-List1, Bank-List2, Education, Ecommerce, Articles, Railway-List1.

Is there is any php function to display?

I got the output for exact match. But no result for this type of search.

Please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [stristr](http://php.net/stristr)

`stristr — Case-insensitive strstr()`

```
<?php    // Example from PHP.net
  $string = 'Hello World!';
  if(stristr($string, 'earth') === FALSE) {
    echo '"earth" not found in string';
  }
// outputs: "earth" not found in string
?>
```

So for your situation, if your list was in an array named `$values`

you could do

```
foreach($values as $value)
{
      if(stristr($value, 'bank') !== FALSE) 
      {
        echo $value."<br>";
      }
}
```

Comment: @raghu If you got solution by this answer post, please mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using **[stristr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php)**. This function returns all of haystack starting from and including the first occurrence of needle to the end. Returns the matched sub-string. If needle is not found, returns FALSE.

Here is the complete code:

```
<?php

  $str="Railway-List, Bank-List1, Bank-List2, Education, Ecommerce, Articles, Railway-List1";
  $findme="bank";
  $tokens= explode(",", $str);
  for($i=0;$i<count($tokens);$i++)
  {
    $trimmed =trim($tokens[$i]);
    $pos = stristr($trimmed, $findme);
    if ($pos === false) {}
    else
    {
        echo $trimmed.",";
    }
  }
?>
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/W1nWEF)**

Answer (score 1):

This solution is only valid for this pattern of text is like: word1, word2, word3

```
<?php
$text = 'Railway-List, Bank-List1, Bank-List2, Education, Ecommerce, Articles, Railway-List1.';


function search_in_text($word, $text){

 $parts = explode(", ", $text);
 $result = array();
 $word = strtolower($word);

 foreach($parts as $v){

  if(strpos(strtolower($v), $word) !== false){
   $result[] = $v;
  }

 }

 if(!empty($result)){
    return implode(", ", $result);
 }else{
    return "not found";
 }
}

echo search_in_text("bank", $text);
echo search_in_text("none", $text);
?>
```

output:

```
Bank-List1, Bank-List2
not found
```